What would be the differences between just inside the event horizon and near the centre of a black hole?
We usually speak of a black hole as if everything inside the event horizon is the same (not including the singularity of course).  But the event horizon of a black hole can be huge. What, if any, are the diffences inside a black hole from near, but inside the event horizon versus near the centre?  Does time run even slower than $c$, if that is something that could be considered?

You need to be more precise about what you are asking. For example are you asking about the experience of the observer falling towards the black hole i.e. do they notice any difference with different distances from the singularity? Or are you asking about the mapping between clocks held by external and internal observers? If the latter note that there is no mapping between external and internal clocks regardless of how far in the internal clock is.

@JohnRennie the reason I'm not being more precise is because I have no idea of what any potential differences would be.  This is the reason for my question.  But for certain I am not asking about anything inside that maps to anything outside the event horizon.  I am asking about differences inside the event horizon.  We speak of the black hole as a uniform region.  I want to know if that is correct?

@foolishmuse I have never head of a blackhole described as "a uniform region", and the Schwarzschild metric isn't uniform. There's also Kruskal–Szekeres coordinates, Gullstrand–Painlevé coordinates and Eddington–Finkelstein coordinates for studying the geometry....and that's for $J=0$. With the Kerr metric you have two horizons, a ringularity, an ergosphere and so on...it's all it but much for a mere PSE answer.

"Time running" at all is ill-defined inside a black hole. You can still speak of the $t$-coordinate, but for $r<r_s$ (inside the event horizon) the $t$-coordinate is spacelike and the other three coordinates are timelike. This behavior, among others, extends from $r=r_s-\epsilon$ to $r=\epsilon$, just before the singularity. You also find that inside the event horizon there aren't causal curves that can bring you outside - no matter what path you take, you're going inwards. Which effect are you asking about the change in? This is a good question but needs to be more specific to be answerable.

@JEB great answer and just the kind of thing I was looking for.   Now I can do some research on those things to find out more.  But of course I did not know that these things existed so I could not ask about them.

@controlgroup What does it mean when you say the t coordinate is spacelike?  That's a good response.  And of course since I did not know that this exists, I could not be more specific in asking about it.

Ordinarily $t/tau$ (time) and $x/y/z/r/\phi/\theta/$whatever other coordinates you use (space) have opposite signs. Sign is arbitrary - I prefer timelike terms to be positive and spacelike terms to be negative, others use other signatures - but inside the event horizon those signs flip for $t$ and $r$ in regular spherical coordinates. For an infalling observer this means that previously-spacelike curves become timelike and vice versa, which forces the observer to travel ever-inwards. You can see this for yourself with a simple construction of the Schwarzschild metric; it's a good exercise.

Higher-order curvature invariants like the Kretschmann scalar increase.

Space inside has a different shape. It is infinite in one direction, but finite in the other two (if you fly straight, you would’ve made a full circle and came back, I you had enough time, but you don’t). No direction in space points to outside, which no longer exists, or to the singularity, which doesn’t exist yet. The tidal forces stretch you along the infinite dimension. As time moves on, the other two dimensions become smaller, as if you are being squeezed in a long narrow “tube” while the tidal forces increase. In the end you are pulled and squashed into a thin line called a singularity.

@safesphere what you have described is basically uniform inside the EH.  It does that everywhere.  I'm wondering more about differences based on elevation above the centre.

The center you refer to is not a location in space, but a moment of time happening everywhere at once. You don’t move to the singularity, there is no direction that points to it. Instead you just wait for it to happen everywhere just like midnight in your city. Two main things change in the process, as noted above: (1) the tidal forces increase stretching you in one direction; (2) the space around you in the other 2 directions shrinks squeezing you as if into an increasingly thinner “tube”. Your time also slows down, but this is moot, because you can’t know if your time moved faster yesterday.

This of course is a simplification, but hopefully good enough for the intuitive picture. Strictly speaking, the “tube” above is a 3D (hyper)surface of a 4D (hyper)cylinder of the spherical type called spherinder: http://hi.gher.space/wiki/Spherinder - So it is like you are being squeezed not inside the “tube” but into the “wall” of the tube. If you and I fall at the same time from the opposite directions, we would be squeezed into the opposite. “walls” of the “tube” and never meet before this “tube” shrinks to zero when time ends.

@safesphere so you are saying that pressure increases as  you move in the only direction in which you can move.

I think that this discussion would be better had in the form of a specific question receiving a specific answer than in comments. There are a lot of things that happen as you go through the event horizon and towards the singularity; asking about one of them instead of all of them would be better.

@foolishmuse Just imagine yourself in a squeezing tube. If you are surrounded by air, the pressure would increase. If you fall in a vacuum, there would be no pressure (at least up to some point), just less room. You do move along the infinite direction, but you could use your rocket engines to stop. This makes no difference, because this direction is not toward the singularity. While inside, you are moving toward the singularity in time, not in space, so your movement in space is irrelevant. See the last diagram here for details: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/426143/427025#427025

curved time is hard to imagine. Sometimes I think about going backwards-in-time to the Big Bang, so we get squished to a singularity that happens everywhere at the same time (as @safesphere described). It's not perfect, but helps. Also: larger radii are in the past, you can't get to them on a time-like trajectory.

@foolishmuse thanks for the "+" feedback. I would have kept the question open, that it "lacked clarity" was the question. and that it's generated lots of activity means ppl are interested. Check out Kip Thorne's series on "Closer To Truth", e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tiocBE51yuc&list=PLFJr3pJl27pItxUFeZlx98GQzl-5UBroJ and related. Any BH fact that I parrot is something I learned in his GR class, whether I understand it or not. (Fun fact: Andrea Ghez was also in the class, so that's a lot of Nobel BH action in one room).
